# Google oAuth2 API gives a 401 UNAUTHORIZED

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-social, google-oauth

I'm trying to implement the Google oAuth2 API for login to my webapp using google credentials via Spring Social.

The query to Google is as follows

```
    googleConnectionFactory = new GoogleConnectionFactory(myKey, mySecret);
    oauthOperations = googleConnectionFactory.getOAuthOperations();
    final String redirectUri = "http://localhost/googleCallback";
    final OAuth2Parameters params = new OAuth2Parameters();
    params.setRedirectUri(redirectUri);
    params.setScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile");
    final String authorizeUrl = oauthOperations.buildAuthorizeUrl(
            GrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE, params);
    response.sendRedirect(authorizeUrl);
```

Once requested, I am taken to the Google login page. The URL shows `scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile`

Once logged in, the user is redirected back to my webapp and the method below is called

```
    final String callbackUrl = "http://localhost/googleCallback";
    final AccessGrant accessGrant = oauthOperations.exchangeForAccess(code,
            callbackUrl, null);
    // THIS CRASHES WITH 401
    final Connection<Google> connection = googleConnectionFactory
            .createConnection(accessGrant);
    // THIS CRASHES TOO WITH 401
    new GoogleTemplate(accessGrant.getAccessToken()).userOperations().getUserProfile();
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Is **accessGrant.accessToken** populated by Google?

Answer (score 3):

I had to manually concatenate the access token to the API url in order to get it to work. Apparently Spring Social doesn't set the Access Token while sending the query...

```
LegacyGoogleProfile profile = new GoogleTemplate(
accessGrant.getAccessToken()).getRestTemplate().getForObject(
"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?access_token="
                    + accessGrant.getAccessToken(),
LegacyGoogleProfile.class);
```

Comment: It's somewhat better practice (more secure) to send the access token as an HTTP header (Authorization: Bearer <token goes here>). Reason is that jamming it into the URL means that it likely gets logged on the server side.

Comment: I agree. This was a workaround. I really don't know why `googleConnectionFactory.createConnection(accessGrant);` would crash though while they both have the same (and correct) access token..

Comment: Just to be clear, the issue you're having is with Spring Social Google, not with Spring Social itself. Spring Social Google is a community-led project, led by Gabriel Axel. I'm sure that Gabriel would appreciate knowing about this problem. May I suggest that you submit an issue or (better yet) a pull request to his project at https://github.com/GabiAxel/spring-social-google.